Copy activity - File is having 3 columns but Sink Table is having 5 columns - ADF
I have source file with different record layouts and trying to load the data into same table in Synapse Analytics - dedicated sql spool. I am trying to use Dynamic Column mapping approach but getting an error
Steps : Set Variable
Copy Activity
File : dept.csv 
SourceID,SourceName
1,HR
2,Finance
3,IT
4,Marketing

Table :
create table dept
(
    dept_id INT,
    dept_name VARCHAR(100),
    location VARCHAR(100)
);

Error : Copy Activity Error :
"errors": [
    {
        "Code": 22301,
        "Message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Column count in target table does not match column count specified in input. If BCP command, ensure format file column count matches destination table. If SSIS data import, check column mappings are consistent with target.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=107098,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=107098,State=1,Message=Column count in target table does not match column count specified in input. If BCP command, ensure format file column count matches destination table. If SSIS data import, check column mappings are consistent with target.,}

Create Set Variable - Using Dynamic Mapping:
{
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "mappings": [
        {
            "source": {
                "name": "SourceID",
                "type": "int",
                "physicalType": "String"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "dept_id",
                "type": "Int32",
                "physicalType": "int"
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "name": "SourceName",
                "type": "String",
                "physicalType": "String"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "dept_name",
                "type": "String",
                "physicalType": "varchar"
            }
        }
    ]
}


Why don't you use auto create table in sink instead of dynamic mapping, it will create new table with same columns of file.

I have 15 different file record layouts and need to load in one final table. So looking for dynamic mapping instead of 15 different tables.

As your source files column names and columns order are different to each other, It will become complex task to build the required mapping of every table. You can try the below workaround using the combination of Data flow activity and copy activity inside a For-each activity.
Create a source dataset with dataset parameter for the filename and clear the Schema.

Create a dataflow and give this dataset as source. Create below parameters in the dataflow. Create an array parameter and give all your target table column names like below.

This dataflow is for renaming your source column names to target column names and eliminating the extra column which are not in target table. For, this you should have an idea of which source column name should be renamed to the target column name.
For example, the below condition check whether the incoming column name is Source_id and if it's true, renames this to Id. Similarly, you need to do the for all the target column names.
Use select transformation Rule-based mapping for this.

This one renames all the required source column names to the target column names and keeps the extra column names as it is.
Use the next select transformation to remove the extra column with the array parameter that created earlier.
contains($tcolumns,#item==name)


Now, overwrite this data with original source files. For that, give the same source dataset for the sink as well. To get a single file as output follow the below settings in the dataflow sink.

In the pipeline, use a Get meta data activity to get the file names list as Child items. Give this array to For-each activity. Inside For-each call the above dataflow and provide all the necessary values to the dataset parameters and dataflow parameter.
Provide @item().name to the dataset parameters in the dataflow activity settings and the same value to the filename parameter and no need to change values for tcolumns array parameter as the default value for this was already given in the dataflow itself.

Then, use copy activity with same csv dataset as source and your target table as sink. Give @item().name to the dataset parameter.

Don't import any mapping any columns in the mapping and leave it as it is.

Debug the pipeline. For-each file, the dataflow will rename the required columns and removes the extra column and overwrites this data to the same file. Then, the copy activity will copy those columns to the target table. The casting of the values will be done by the copy activity itself as the column names are matching.
The NULL values will be assigned for the extra columns of the target table.

